# JOIN after WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next code:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT count FROM table_log 
        WHERE event_id = table2.id)
    JOIN table2 ON table2.type = 'user'
```

and I am getting next error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "JOIN"
LINE 8:       JOIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the syntax  you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2)
   SELECT table2.val1, table2.val2
   FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_log l WHERE l.event_id = table2.id) AND
         table2.type = 'user'
```